# CiviCRM settings file does not exist

Tags: drupal, installation

Drupal 7.32, Attempted install of CiviCRM 4.6.9.

---

I do not yet have direct access to the server or database, that power rests in another's hands. 
Installation goes off without a hitch, all requirements clear and the 'Modules' overlay confirms CiviCRM is installed.
Any attempt to enable CiviCRM produces the error:

> (Currently using CiviCRM settings does not exist CiviCRM settings
>   file does not exist. It should be created by CiviCRM install)

It refuses activation.

Comment: It sounds like you did this, but just to confirm, you visited the installer URL rather than just trying to enable it like any other module, right? http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC46/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7#InstallingCiviCRMforDrupal7-4.RuntheInstaller

Comment: Your are correct

Comment: Does civicrm.settings.php exist in sites/default?  Does it have sufficient permissions to be readable?

Comment: I would certainly check the permissions!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused here - you say that the Modules overlay confirms it's installed, but any attempt to enable it produces the error. You shouldn't have to enable it anywhere - you run the install page and then it is installed and automatically enabled in Drupal.

So on the modules page is it just listed there, or is it checked to show that it is actually turned on?

I want to make sure where we stand on that before looking at other causes.